# Start PowerShell or Python script when USB drive is detached

Tags: python, powershell

I have token for connecting AnyConnect VPN. I want a script that when the USB token disconnected it runs and ends the VPN connection.
What is the best way for it?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! If you already haven't, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried until this point ?

Comment: *"What is the best way for it?"* Starting your preferred editor and writing a script, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

A brief rundown on an idea that you can employ.

On Windows Eventviewer, navigate to
`Application and Service Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> DriverFrameworks-UserMode`

And enable that log if it already isn't. It was disabled for me in Windows 10.

Now, adding and removing USB devices will generate a log here. You should be able to do some research and find out which log makes most sense to you.

Once you know what eventid to look for, you can use the Windows `taskscheduler` to trigger on the generation of an event.

[image]

Now you can have the task scheduler invoke a PowerShell script that does what you need. [This](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/otto/2007/11/09/reference-the-event-that-triggered-your-task/) will help you setup the task. Unfortunately, we cannot write that script for you. If you need to understand why, please look [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). We can help when you get stuck. I hope this will get you started in the right direction. Cheers!